# What's the difference between "slave start" and "start slave"

Tags: mysql, database, replication

as the title saying,
What's the difference between "slave start" and "start slave"?
when i was interviewed by a DBA,he asked this problem, I searched google but found no answer,anyone knows?

Comment: Both does the same I guess ..

Comment: A stupid question to ask in an interview. `SLAVE START` was the syntax prior to MySQL 5.0, which came out *ten years ago.* A candidate applying now shouldn't be expected to know that. Yet another interviewer showing off.

Answer (score 0):

No difference..

`Slave start;` is deprecated and now command to start a slave is `Start slave;`